# AWS-Lamda fails because can't import variable outside lambda_handler

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I checked all question asked before here and didn't find answer.
I have the following structure of my project:

```
project/
├── 
└── lambdas
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── lambda_handler_1.py  # def main(event, context)
    ├── lambda_handler_2.py
└── my_lib
    ├── __init__.py. # Here I have `import my_lids.utils \n import my_lids.exceptions`
    ├── exceptions.py
    ├── utils.py
└── api
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── some_api.py  # Here I make `from my_lids.utils import my_func` and `from my_lids.exceptions import MyException`
```

When trigger runs lambda's I'm getting error

```
Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambdas/lambda_handler_1': cannot import name 'my_func' from 'my_lib.errors' (/var/task/my_lib/utils.py)
```

I do not use any function from module utils in my lambda. What do I do wrong?
I archived all my code and requirements into zip file and deploy it. Also there aren't any `__pycache__`, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A Lambda Function can contain multiple files.

If you use `utils.py` only for that function, then you should include its source as another file for the function

If that's the case, then put each Lambda Function in its own folder (not individual files), add utils.py to the folder of the Lambda you want to use it with. Then use the SAM CLI to build/package/deploy your Lambdas

If you use it in multiple places, you should package it as a Lambda Layer

Lambda Layers are a pain to update, however

PS you don't need to install Docker when installing the SAM ClI

Comment: To be honest `utils.py` is using in API only. I don't use it within any lambda function